# How to read date and time from csv in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, time-series

I am getting an error in time series date-time parsing function. The data is [attached](https://ufile.io/jbe10). I tried this to read the Date and time column.

```
Data = pd.read_csv('Data.csv', header=0, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, squeeze=True, date_parser=parser)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `strptime()` function needs to be formatted exactly as the timestamp is formatted, including slashes and colons. You can find the details on [the python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

In this case, your timestamp is formatted as `1/1/2016 0:00` but your string format `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"` is expecting `2016-1-1 0:00`. If you use `'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'` as your format string then the `strptime()` function works as expected. For example:

```
import datetime as dt

with open('datac.csv','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        try:
            time = line.split(',')[0] #splits the line at the comma and takes the first bit
            time = dt.datetime.strptime(time, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
            print(time)
        except:
            pass
```

You should be able to adapt your code with this in mind.